# iPhone bookmark link add to home screen?

Tags: iphone, bookmarks

Is it possible to add a link that bookmarks to the home screen?

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure what John ment was if it's possible to put the link on the webpage so that the user doesn't need to press the plus key.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand the question the answer is: press plus key in Safari, then "Add to Home Screen".

Answer (score 2):

Funny answers above. Chris asked if this can be done programatically from the web app. 
E.g. I put a big button saying "Add to home-screen" on my webpage, access it from Safari, click the big button, done.

Comment: A smart solution is posted by 'deceze" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone, in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use this script: http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

Answer (score 0):

how about reading the choices when pressing + key? it asks u if u want to add to home. hope this answers ur query.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a programmatic way to do this, however there are scripts which draw a user's attention to the fact that they can do it manually.

[Add to Home Screen](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) is one such option.

[Mobile Bookmark Bubble](https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/wiki/Mobile-Bookmark-Bubble) is another.