# iPhone webClip browser app suggestions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-clips

I want do build an webclip browser app. I will display all my webclips in to a scroll view when the user taps on one I want to add that web clip to the iPhone.
How to I tell to the iOS to install that webclip from my app?

Any docs, example, tutorials are welcome.

Comment: Be more specific of what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `webclip` you mean adding a link to a web address to the home screen then you can't do that programatically.

I think only Safari can do this so you would have to open the destination webpage in Safari and instruct the user how to add it to the home screen.

See this for a discussion on the feature. [Javascript for "Add to Home Screen" on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone)

Comment: Web Clip is the Apple name for the home-screen bookmark feature.