# iOS add home screen shortcut programmatically

Tags: ios

I would like to add a home screen shortcut programmtically to a custom URL from within my iOS application (not mobile Safari). The URL doesn't have to be an http:// URL. It can be, for example, myProtocol://

Is it even possible in iOS? any alternative if it is not?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone/4976474#4976474

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think you can do that. Fortunately – as developers would misuse it to no end.

Comment: I only want to use it to bookmark an html page that run in an embedded UIWebView. There should not be any difference in terms of misuse by developers.