# iphone, add home screen icon automatically

Tags: iphone, xcode, homescreen

is it possible to have an icon on the iPhone home screen, programtically without user doing it. I mean , when you visit Youtube on your iPhone, it asks you to add a home screen button, which you click and then it takes you directly to the youtube page. I need to know that if it's possible to add a home screen button automatically , without even asking the user to add it.

Comment: You don't like respecting your app's users?

Comment: You are talking about web application right?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - **No**.

Little longer answer - if sites will have rights without user permission add web-apps on springboard, allow location services and so on. This is mess... Thats why you can't do such thing due to privacy & permissions.
Maybe on jailbroken iOS, but not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant have the shortcut for the home screen. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone) will assure you that.
However, there's a slightly related [solution](http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/).