# iOs And Android: create a bookmark -shortcut- in homescreen by javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, bookmarks

I am developing a web cross-browser app.

I want that, clicking on "ADD HOME" icon, **by Javascript detects the OS** (Android, iOs, BB...) **and creates a Shortcut (bookmark) on the HomeScreen**.

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on iOS(4.x) it isn't possible.

Read [Javascript for "Add to Home Screen" on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone) for details. As it is suggested, you can add a bubble, dialog or some other information to guide the user for using iOS's own functionality.

Comment: Ok, I´ve read more about it and this is the only solution... :(.

So I have to write a program who redirect to the browser.

Thanks.