# Is it possible to make a button 'add to homescreen' for the iphone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, iphone-web-app, iphone-standalone-web-app

Im new to developing webablications for the iphone. I wonder if it is possible to add a button who has the simular function as the '+ add to homescreen' button to your website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript for "Add to Home Screen" on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that has to be done from the browser's UI.

Several web apps show an arrow pointing to the 'add to homescreen' button along with an encouraging message.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this isn't possible.

However there are good tutorials and snippets available for guiding the user, like http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen .

Comment: Ok thanks. It was the answer i expected, nevertheless I hoped that there was a way to do it. Too bad there isn't.

Comment: You should really accept the answer, even if it was bad news :)