# Implement "Add to Home Screen" in mobile website. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript for “Add to Home Screen” on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone)

Is it possible to launch "Add to Home Screen" popup on click on any link or button? May be using javascript or html5.

I have one mobile website where client wants if user click on a link then it should be added to home screen.

Needs this to be implemented of iPad.

If not possible then what alternative do you suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You might find this useful: http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

> I found that many iPhone and iPad users don’t know that they can add
>   their favorite web sites to the Home Screen and interact with them
>   like standard native applications. [...] The script places a floating balloon inviting the
>   user to add your application to the home screen. Version 2 of the
>   script takes advantage of iOS5 native fixed elements positioning and
>   gracefully degrades to a javascript only version on iOS4.

Comment: This is a floating bubble. I want something on user click. May be display this bubble on click?

Comment: Link doesn't work