# how to programmatically create a desktop shortcut for a website on android/ios with js?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, shortcut

is there a way to let the user add a desktop shortcut of a website with just javascript or a simple link? I mean on mobile devices, especially android and ios.

There are other questions similar to this but they didn't give me a useful answer till now.

Comment: According to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone) you can't do this on iOS, but you can use this [script](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) to add a pop-up helping the user to add a shorcut to iOS home screen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about android, but on iOS no.  I'm not sure why you would want to do this anyway in mobile safari it's as simple as clicking the share button in the tool bar and the click "add to home screen"

Comment: So "no" is not a valid answer?