# Add bookmark of website with specified logo icon to the home screen of mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to add bookmark of my website to home screen of mobile. the bookmark should contain the specified icon. I would expect expect how exactly weather.com works on iPhone like - share button tap takes you to next page where you have "add bookmark", "add to favs" etc, then tap "add bookmark" which displays website icon along with two editable fields - one for url and other for name.

Any help about how to get this functionality will be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you ever even tried to search for this by yourself? I tried with _add bookmark of my website to home screen of mobile_ exactly as you write and i found many solutions...

Comment: Yes, I did a lot of search but no luck up to my understanding. I could find this but don't know how to customize it to my requirement.
http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

if you can explain me the steps to follow would be appreciated. All I need is how to get my website icon added to the bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can force a bookmark add, but there are ways to prompt your user with instructions so they can do it. You might benefit from this thread:
[Javascript for "Add to Home Screen" on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone)

specifically:

https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen

http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen